# Current Post Parent Category & Child Category Links

Tags: navigation

On a template that I'm building, within the single.php I need to have links to the parent category & child category. Each post will only have one parent category & one child category.

My url structure for the post would look like this:

> /kia/sportage/kia-sportage-2-0/

The category urls would then look like this:

> /category/kia/ and /category/kia/sportage/

so far I've used the following code:

```
<a href="<?php
$cat = get_the_category();
$cat = $cat[0];
echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
?>"> <?php
$category = get_the_category();
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?></a>
```

This links to the */category/kia/sportage/* url with the anchor text of *Sportage*

I also need to create a link to */category/kia/* with the anchor text of *Kia*, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Display the categories (or terms from other taxonomies) assigned to a
>   post ordered by parent-child category relationship. Similar to the
>   function get_the_category_list() which orders the categories by name.
>   This example must be used inside the loop.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category';

// Get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms(
    $post->ID,
    $taxonomy,
    array(
        'fields' => 'ids'
    )
);

// Separator between links.
$separator = ', ';

if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

    $terms = wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids
    ) );

    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // Display post categories.
    echo  $terms;
}
```

Source: [user contributed example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#div-comment-1169) from the Developer's Code Reference.